# кнопка - блок или ссылка?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше реализовывать такую кнопку?

Первый вариант:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  width: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">load more</a>
</div>
```

Или же второй вариант:

```css
a {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 padding: 3px 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: red;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
```

```html
<a href="#">load more</a>
```

Comment: А зачем использовать тег `<a>`, если это не ссылка...  Все зависит от того, что делает кнопка... Если не ссылка, так и тег `<a>` не надо использовать...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если это кнопка, то надо использовать тег `<button type="button">load more</button>` если же у этого элемента предназначение переадресовывать пользователя куда-то дальше, то делай ссылкой.

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант через ссылку кажется значительно проще и лучше, ссылки приспособлены уже к перенаправлению, а через "тык" по div это все таки костыль, так же как и использовать div, а внутри него button